# Ratchet how check if user is not authorized

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

At the moment method `onOpen` contains following code

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
 {
        // store the new connection
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
       // echo "someone connected\n";
}
```

I want to add authorization data (token) in order to ignore hacker requests.

How I want to do it:

method `onOpen` gets parameter "token" and checks if the user is authorized.

In case if the user is a crasher, the method doesn't add this user to clients list.

Thus unauthorized users will be not able to receive updates.

I know I can to do following

in javascript:

```
new WebSocket('ws://server.com:8080?token=secret')
```

in php:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
{
    $querystring = $conn->httpRequest->getUri()->getQuery();
    parse_str($querystring,$queryarray);

    if(!isValid($queryarray['token'])) {
      return;
    }

    // store the new connection
    $this->clients->attach($conn);
    // echo "someone connected\n";
}
```

But I think it's not safe.

What do you think about it? Could you help me, please?

Maybe there are other methods to check authorized users?

Comment: Initially, WebSocket handshake is done via HTTP request and response so using session(cookie) you can authorize the connection.

Comment: @pathikdevani I have to use exactly token, not cookie. How can I pass this parameter to onOpen method?

Comment: onOpen is called when WebSocket connected was established. first, you have to send one token(using send method) with some key so a server can authenticate a client and after authorize further communication work.

Comment: https://github.com/pathikdevani/Flysync/blob/387085c30f2f6e0759d89d7655d3926d6550cd86/flysync-android/flysync/src/main/java/com/pathik/server/main/WSMain.java#L59 code snippet in java

Comment: @pathikdevani, thanks alot for your help. It was very useful for me